# why the axesHelper function doesn't show the axis on the screen?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have some problem with my code. I'm using three.js and trying to initialize the components. Objects that are initialized do not display on the screen like axis, cube. Please indicate where the error may be.

```
function gameInit(axlesHelper) {
  (axlesHelper) ? gameComponent.setAxlesHelper() : null ;
  gameComponent.setAambientLight();
  gameComponent.setDirectionalLight();
  gameComponent.setCameraPosition();
  gameComponent.renderer();
}

var gameComponent = {
  scene : new THREE.Scene(),
  axesHelper : new THREE.AxesHelper( 10 ),
  ambientLight : new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0,6),
  directionalLight : new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1),
  aspect : window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  width : 10,
  height : this.width / this.aspect,
  camera : new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    this.width * -2, // left
    this.width * 2, // right
    this.height * 2, // top
    this.height * -2, // bottom
    0, // near plane
    10000 // far plane
  ),
  render : new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias : true}),
  
  setAxlesHelper : function() {
    console.log('wywołano axlesHelper');
    this.scene.add( this.axesHelper );
  },
  .
  .
  .
  renderer : function(){
    console.log('wywołano renderer');
    this.render.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.render.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    document.body.appendChild(this.render.domElement);
  },
  rendererUpdate : function(){
    console.log('wywołano renderer update');
    this.render.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

}
gameInit(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  height : this.width / this.aspect,
  camera : new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    this.width * -2, // left
    this.width * 2, // right
    this.height * 2, // top
    this.height * -2, // bottom
    0, // near plane
    10000 // far plane
  ),
```

This code is not valid. Accessing properties via `this` results in `undefined`. Hence, you camera holds `NaN` values which breaks the rendering. Try it like so:

```js
function gameInit(axlesHelper) {
  (axlesHelper) ? gameComponent.setAxlesHelper(): null;
  gameComponent.renderer();
}

const width = 10;
const height = width / ( window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight );

var gameComponent = {
  scene: new THREE.Scene(),
  axesHelper: new THREE.AxesHelper(10),
  ambientLight: new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0, 6),
  directionalLight: new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1),
  camera: new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    width * -2, // left
    width * 2, // right
    height * 2, // top
    height * -2, // bottom
    0, // near plane
    10000 // far plane
  ),
  render: new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  }),

  setAxlesHelper: function() {
    this.scene.add(this.axesHelper);
  },

  renderer: function() {
    this.render.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.render.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    document.body.appendChild(this.render.domElement);
  },
  rendererUpdate: function() {
    console.log('wywołano renderer update');
    this.render.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

}
gameInit(true);
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.136.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
```